# How to import/ embed / modify an Excel file into a MS Word file using python

Tags: python, excel, flask, ms-word

I need to make an Invoice that has an embedded Excel file into it. This file either should be imported from a different Excel file, or complete the values for a pre-existing embedded excel object in Word. This is the main condition of this program -  that the user may need to modify his invoice later by adding more merchandise in the embedded Excel file, and the sum and totals have to be updated accordingly.

*I do NOT need to populate a Word Table with values from an Excel table, I need an Excel file inserted in Word!*

Some ways that I tried - **in Python/ Flask**

1. I created an excel helper file with all the necessary values and then I want to copy it in the word file - only the data gets copied, without the Excel functionality.

```
def create_document_Fcompany_Invoice(id):
    client_invoice = Client.query.get_or_404(id)
    currency = request.form.get('currency')
    # Extract products data
    products_json = request.form.get('products')
    if products_json:
        products = json.loads(products_json)
        print(products)
    else:
        products = []

    # Create a new workbook and select the active sheet
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    # Add header
    kg_price_header = "Kg Price " + currency
    total_price_header = "Total Price " + currency
    headers = ["Quantity", "Product", "Type", "Package (kg)", "Net Weight", kg_price_header, total_price_header]

    modified_headers = []
    for header in headers:
        words = header.split()
        if len(words) > 2:
            half_index = len(words) // 2
            modified_headers.append(' '.join(words[:half_index]) + "\n" + ' '.join(words[half_index:]))
        else:
            modified_headers.append(header)

    # Adjust header column width and height
    for col_num, header in enumerate(modified_headers, 1):
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num)].width = 12
        ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 30

    # Use modified_headers to populate the Excel sheet
    for col_num, header in enumerate(modified_headers, 1):
        cell = ws.cell(row=1, column=col_num, value=header)
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center', wrap_text=True)
        cell.font = Font(bold=True)

    # Add data
    for row_num, product in enumerate(products, 2):  # Starting from row 2 because headers are on row 1
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=1, value=product["drum_quantity"])
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=2, value=product["product_name"])
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=3, value=product["product_type"])
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=4, value=product["package"])
        drum_quantity = product["drum_quantity"]
        package_weight = product["package"]
        net_weight = int(drum_quantity) * int(package_weight)
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=5, value=net_weight)
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=6, value=product["kg_price"])
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=7, value=product["total_price"])

    # Add total price
    total_price = sum([int(product["total_price"]) for product in products])
    ws.cell(row=row_num + 2, column=7, value=currency + " " + str(total_price))
    ws.cell(row=row_num + 2, column=1, value="TOTAL COST")

    # Make it Bold and Centered
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

    # Edit word file
    original_doc_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'Original Documents', 'Fcompany_Invoice.docx')
    document = Document(original_doc_path)

    # Ensure the directories exist
    directory = f"generated_documents/{client_invoice.name}"
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)

    # Save the Excel file
    excel_file = f"generated_documents/{client_invoice.name}/Fcompany_Excel_Helper_{client_invoice.id}.xlsx"
    wb.save(excel_file)
    wb.close()

    document_path = f"generated_documents/{client_invoice.name}/Fcompany_Invoice_{client_invoice.id}.docx"
    # Save the document
    document.save(document_path)
    document.close()

    client_invoice.document_name = document_path
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(f"/select/{client_invoice.id}")  # Redirect to the client details page
```

2. Getting the currently embedded Excel file from Word and trying to manipulate its values.First using OLE-OBjects and Blobs. This approach doesn't do anything.

```
    # Extract values from the range and store in a list of lists
    data = []
    for row in cell_range:
        data_row = [cell.value for cell in row]
        data.append(data_row)
    book.close()

    print("we have these tables:", document.tables)
    for shape in document.inline_shapes:
        if shape.Type == win32.constants.wdInlineShapeEmbeddedOLEObject:
            ole_format = shape.OLEFormat
            ole_format.Activate()  # This will open the embedded Excel worksheet
            excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
            ws = excel.ActiveSheet
            ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = 'New Value'  # Update cell A1

            excel.Application.Quit()

    # Step 3: Access the embedded Excel object (assuming there's only one)
    ole_obj = None
    excel_rel = None
    for rel in document.part.rels.values():
        if 'embeddings/Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet1.xlsx' in rel.target_ref:
            ole_obj = rel.target_part.blob
            excel_rel = rel
            print(' we got the blob,', ole_obj)

    # Step 3.2: If there's no embedded Excel object, return an error and show the embedded objects
    embedded_objects = [rel.target_ref for rel in document.part.rels.values()]

    print(embedded_objects)
    if not ole_obj:
        return f"No embedded Excel object found. Found these embedded objects: {embedded_objects}", 400

    # Step 4: Modify the Excel content with openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(BytesIO(ole_obj))
    ws = wb.active

    row_offset = 2  # You can adjust this if you want to start inserting from a different row
    col_offset = 1  # Similarly, adjust if you want to start from a different column

    for r, row_data in enumerate(data, start=row_offset):
        for c, value in enumerate(row_data, start=col_offset):
            # Convert column number to column letter (e.g., 1 -> 'A', 2 -> 'B', ...)
            col_letter = openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(c)
            ws[f"{col_letter}{r}"].value = value

    # Step 5: Save the modified Excel file
    excel_stream = BytesIO()
    wb.save(excel_stream)

    # Step 5.2: Update the embedded Excel object with the modified Excel file
    ole_obj = excel_stream.getvalue()

    rId = excel_rel.rId
    part = document.part
    new_blob = ole_obj   #
    new_part = part.related_parts[rId]
    new_part._blob = new_blob
    new_part._package = part.package  # This is needed to update the package's content types

    # new_part.clear_content_type_cache()
    # part.rels.replace_relationship(rId, new_part.content_type, new_part)
```

3. I have tried unzipping the docx file, fetching the embedded Excel object, and then recompiling the Word document. The file became corrupt and unusable.

I have been searching for many days now for no clear result...

If you have any idea or solution or tutorial, or maybe even a solution in other languages, please help!